# Spring/Maven localhost prefix (tomcat server)

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

How can I remove `spring-hibernate-template` prefix from my localhost?
Now it is `localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-template`. The local host running on tomcat.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on eclipse or straight on tomcat or other container?

Comment: tomcat via eclipse (edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your project, select properties, go to `Web Project Settings` and change the context path. You'll possibly need to remove the web application from your web server and re-add it.

Comment: Where do I do that ( remove the web application from your web server and re-add it.)

Comment: @VladIoffe In your servers tab, select the tomcat server, then `Add and remove`.